# How to active the tab button?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have three tabs, I use `button` instead of `ul` and `li` tags. I want the first button automatic active or change the color green. I use the active class in bootstrap but it doesn't work at all. How can I do it so the user can know where he/she is? Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heuvkro0/5/

```
  <div class="nav nav-pills mt-4">
    <button class="nav-link active btn btn-sm text-light bg-info font-weight-bold float-left" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <span class="number text-light">1</span> 
            <span class="title text-light font-weight-bold pr-2">Beneficiary Details </span>
    </button>

    <button class="nav-link btn btn-sm text-light bg-info font-weight-bold float-left ml-2" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <span class="number text-light">2</span> 
            <span class="title text-light font-weight-bold pr-2">Dependent Details </span>
    </button>

    <button class="nav-link btn btn-sm text-light bg-info font-weight-bold float-left ml-2" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <span class="number text-light">3</span> 
        <span class="title text-light font-weight-bold pr-2">Complete Details </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom css to `active` class

```
 .nav-link.active {
     background-color: #117a8b !important;
  }
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/wcj5vbxe/4/)